# REGEX in Google Sheets with Filter

Tags: google-sheets, regex, google-sheets-filter, regexextract

I'm trying to mix regex with a filter in Google Sheets. What I have at the moment is

```
=filter(AD:AD,X:X=X2,right(Z:Z,1)={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9})
```

The regular expression is that the final character in column Z is a digit between 1-9 but I cannot figure out how to mix the functions.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula:

`=filter(H2:H7,I2:I7=F2,regexmatch(right(J2:J7,1),"[0-9]"))`

---

**Sample data**

[image: sample]

Comment: This works! Thank you very much

Comment: Great. You might consider [accepting](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer.